# Passing input value from parent window to popup window

Tags: javascript, jsp

I had made a parent window that includes a text box and hyperlink to open a PopUp Child JSP Page.

I wish to access the value entered in textbox on the Child JSP through request.getParameter method. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the value along as querystring in the URL of the popup window.

Assuming that you've a

```
<input type="text" id="foo">
```

you can pass it to the popup window as follows

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo').value;
window.open('child.jsp?foo=' + encodeURIComponent(foo));
```

then you can access it in popup window as follows

```
<p>The value is ${param.foo}</p>
```

Comment: Sounds like he want it the other way around i.e. passing text from child to parent.. as far as I can tell AJAX is the only way isn't it?

Comment: @Shadow: he mentioned to have the textbox in the parent window. Anyway, for the other way round, you can just do `window.opener.document.getElementById('foo').value = newvalue;` on click of the button in the popup window.

Comment: hmm.. on second read you're probably right, guess we'll have to wait for the OP to get back. :)